# How to remove unwanted string from dictionary key value from ansible debug

Tags: regex, parsing, ansible, jinja2, regexp-replace

I have below output when i ran a ansible playbook

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "last-heard-processing-time": "18611 secs ago(took 15 secs)",
            "name": "XXXX",
            "status": "conn:Getting ALL"
        },
        {
            "last-heard-processing-time": "20375 secs ago(took 17 secs)",
            "name": "AAAA",
            "status": "conn:Getting ALL"
        },
        {
            "last-heard-processing-time": "20292 secs ago(took 11 secs)",
            "name": "BBBB",
            "status": "conn:Getting ALL"
        },
        {
            "last-heard-processing-time": "4 secs ago(took 13 secs)",
            "name": "CCCC",
            "status": "conn:idle"
        },
        {
            "last-heard-processing-time": "51 secs ago(took 10 secs)",
            "name": "DDDD",
            "status": "conn:idle"
        },
        {
            "last-heard-processing-time": "53 secs ago(took 10 secs)",
            "name": "EEEEE",
            "status": "conn:idle"
        },
        {
            "last-heard-processing-time": "9 secs ago(took 10 secs)",
            "name": "FFFF",
            "status": "conn:idle"
        }
    ]
}
```

need some help/hint/clue( i am newbie to ansible) from experts on which filter do i need use to remove extra string in 'last-heard-processing-time' key value so that i can get below output, i just need first number in last-heard-processing-time key value

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "last-heard-processing-time": "18611",
            "name": "XXXX",
            "status": "conn:Getting ALL"
        },
        {
            "last-heard-processing-time": "20375",
            "name": "AAAA",
            "status": "conn:Getting ALL"
        },
        {
            "last-heard-processing-time": "20292",
            "name": "BBBB",
            "status": "conn:Getting ALL"
        },
        {
            "last-heard-processing-time": "4",
            "name": "CCCC",
            "status": "conn:idle"
        },
        {
            "last-heard-processing-time": "51",
            "name": "DDDD",
            "status": "conn:idle"
        },
        {
            "last-heard-processing-time": "53",
            "name": "EEEEE",
            "status": "conn:idle"
        },
        {
            "last-heard-processing-time": "9",
            "name": "FFFF",
            "status": "conn:idle"
        }
    ]
}
```

i'm trying to use regex_replace

```
msg: "{{output.msg| regex_replace('\\d+\\ssecs\\sago\\(took\\s\\d+\\ssecs\\)', '\\d+')}}"
```

getting error

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: re.error: bad escape \d at position 0
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the list of the first numbers, .e.g

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        time: "{{ output.msg|
                  map(attribute='last-heard-processing-time')|
                  map('regex_replace', '^(\\d+)\\s+.*$', '\\1') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  time:
  - '18611'
  - '20375'
  - '20292'
  - '4'
  - '51'
  - '53'
  - '9'
```

Then combine the updated dictionaries and concatenate the list

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        out: "{{ out|d([]) +
                 [item.0|combine({'last-heard-processing-time': item.1})] }}"
      with_together:
        - "{{ output.msg }}"
        - "{{ time }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  out:
  - last-heard-processing-time: '18611'
    name: XXXX
    status: conn:Getting ALL
  - last-heard-processing-time: '20375'
    name: AAAA
    status: conn:Getting ALL
  - last-heard-processing-time: '20292'
    name: BBBB
    status: conn:Getting ALL
  - last-heard-processing-time: '4'
    name: CCCC
    status: conn:idle
  - last-heard-processing-time: '51'
    name: DDDD
    status: conn:idle
  - last-heard-processing-time: '53'
    name: EEEEE
    status: conn:idle
  - last-heard-processing-time: '9'
    name: FFFF
    status: conn:idle
```

---

The value of the updated time attribute is a string. Add the *int* filter if you want an integer instead.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        time: "{{ output.msg|
                  map(attribute='last-heard-processing-time')|
                  map('regex_replace', '^(\\d+)\\s+.*$', '\\1')|
                  map('int') }}"
```